# Install Spark on Mac OS

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

Trying to install Spark and associated programs on Mac but receiving error messages when testing installation.

/Users/somedirectory/apachespark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark 
/Users/somedirectory/apachespark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 71: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java: No such file or directory

from my bash_profile entry...

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/

export SPARK_HOME=/Users/directory/apachespark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export SBT_HOME=/Users/directory/apachespark/sbt

export SCALA_HOME=/Users/directory/apachespark/scala-2.11.12

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$PATH

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

correction suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: does `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java` exist?  according to the error message it does not.  should JAVA_HOME maybe be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162/jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java` instead?

Comment: You can avoid all this by just doing brew install apache-spark

Comment: I tried the brew method and after restarting everything works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the reported error message:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

your file path for the Java executable `$JAVA_HOME/bin` generates an extra `/` due to the trailing `/` in your `JAVA_HOME`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

Removing the trailing `/` in `JAVA_HOME` should fix the problem.  Better yet, setting `JAVA_HOME` as shown below would automatically point to the active JDK version on Mac OSX:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```